# Recovery from fastboot

Tags: fastboot

I have a Sanyo Zio that is completely non-functional but for being able to get into fastboot.

Two questions:

1) I gather that the answer to this problem generally is to install a boot.img from fastboot.  Is this correct?

2) Is there a place where such boot images are archived?  Search as I may, I can't find such a site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about this phone, but this [thread on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8169983&postcount=37) has dump of the stock ROM. I am not sure if it includes the boot.img or not. The dump seems to be android 1.6, the [original thread is here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=769571) and is HUGE.

There is also a 2.2 [thread here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11557060) and it does look like the Zio has its [own section](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1060) on XDA as well. In the Development section, i found [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=819104). It has the boot.img, but someone posted saying they were unable to use them. I would suggest sending a PM to the person that pulled the boot.img off the device in that thread.

I hope this helps you in some way... I know what it's like to brick a phone, good luck.